# R Markdown: Importing R script objects

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an R code that generates several plots and tables from my data. I want to write a report in Rmarkdown in which i want to include just the plots and the tables without rewriting the R code. One way is to use 'read_chunk' function but it does not serve my purpose. Following is a simple example of what i need.

Suppose I have the following R script 'Example.r'

```
x <- 1:4
y <- sin(x)

####----Table
table  <- cbind(x,y)
####----Plot
plot_1 <- plot(x,y)
```

Now in my R markdown file i want the following:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('Example.r')
``` 
The following table shows the results:
```{r Table, echo=FALSE}
```
One can depict the result in a plot as well:
```{r Plot, echo=FALSE}
```
````

In the above example, i will not be able to insert either the table or the plot, since both need the input 'x' and 'y' to be defined before the table and the plot commands are run. Is there a way to implement this without hardcoding 'x' and 'y' two times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sourcing an R script, here is my workflow which might be useful to you:
(sorry I feel it should be a comment but it gets a bit lengthy)

- Keep a draft.rmd and a report.rmd side by side. the draft.rmd will be your workplace with exploratory data analysis. and the report.rmd will be your polished report
- Gather results (like data.frames & ggplot objects) you want to put in the report in a list. Save the list as a `result_181023.rda` file. in a folder like `data/`
- Load the saved `result_181023.rda` file in the report.rmd, draw your figures & print your tables and polish your report the way you like.

An example:

````
```{r data echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
# a list named result.list
# With a table result.list$df 
# and a ggplot object: result.list$gg1
load("data/result_181023.rda")

``` 

The following table shows the results:

```{r Table, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(result.list$df)
```

One can depict the result in a plot as well:
```{r Plot, echo=FALSE}
result.list$gg1
```
````

Comment: Thank You. This does solve my purpose, but it takes away the flexibility of formatting and resizing the images in the Rmarkdown report.

Comment: hi @user10543455, no it doesn't. You could use the code chunk options to format the final looks of the image. [See the available chunk options for figures from here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html#figures)

Comment: @user10543455 If this solves your problem, pls accept it so others don't have to spend time on this one. And,  Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks @Zhang. I realized that a better way for me was not to use Rmarkdown but Latex and incorporate the tables using xtable and plots using the graphics package. The code chunks could also be included using knitr package in Latex. This choice is mainly driven by me being in the academia, even though i find Rmarkdown much easier to use. This following link made it easier for me to choose: [https://yihui.name/en/2013/10/markdown-or-latex/]